# Ember js function prints source code instead its actual value

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I cannot understand why this doesn't prints the actual sum (=3) but the source code instead

**Component**

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({

  message: function(){
    let sum = 1+2
    return sum
  }
})
```

**templates**

```
{{message}}
```

this prints the source code as a string!

> function () { let sum = 1 + 2; return sum; }

Comment: Did you need to call it maybe? `{{message()}}`

Comment: Compiling error.Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is referred to as a [computed property](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/computed-properties)
:

```
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({

  message: computed(function(){
    let sum = 1 + 2;
    return sum
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the function before assiging it to `message`. You can do that by either defining the function beforehand and calling it like this:

```
export default Component.extend({

    function a(){
        let sum = 1+2
        return sum
    }

    message: a();
})
```

Or you can immediately invoke the function using the [immediately invoked function express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) approach by wrapping the function in parentheses and calling it right after like this:

```
export default Component.extend({

  message: (function(){
    let sum = 1+2
    return sum
  })();
})
```

Comment: Please don't do this in ember code, we have computed properties for this exact reason, while this example is simple you usually need to access the object via `this` from within such properties

Comment: well, thats *actually* the point! If this *is* a static value this might be OK, but then the question is *why* you need to compute it at all!

Comment: I m going on a limb here and assuming that the OP asked the question with a simple use case but this is definitely not something they will be using in their actual application.